# Not able to register a user. How do I do that?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I know nothing about, how to register a user, using *smack api* . Looking at their documentation and seeing the `Registration` class. I wrote this code. But I guess this doesn't register the user. Though the code runs fine i.e without an error or exception, I don't see the database table getting populated with these values.

```
Registration r = new Registration();

    /*
     *  name -- the user's name.
        first -- the user's first name.
        last -- the user's last name.
        email -- the user's email address.
        city -- the user's city.
        state -- the user's state.
        zip -- the user's ZIP code.
        phone -- the user's phone number.
        url -- the user's website.
        date -- the date the registration took place.
        misc -- other miscellaneous information to associate with the account.
        text -- textual information to associate with the account.
        remove -- empty flag to remove account.
     */

    Map<String,String> regAttr = new HashMap<String, String>();

    regAttr.put("username", "suhail");
    regAttr.put("first", "suhail");
    regAttr.put("last", "gupta");
    regAttr.put("email", "pqr@lmn.com");
    regAttr.put("city", "ptk");
    regAttr.put("state", "Punjab");
    regAttr.put("zip", "145001");
    regAttr.put("phone","9999");
    regAttr.put("url", "www.abc.com");
    regAttr.put("date", "14/8/2013");
    regAttr.put("misc", "misc");
    regAttr.put("text", "text");
    regAttr.put("remove", "r");

    r.setAttributes(regAttr);
```

How do I register a user using *smack api* ?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson I could write nothing except this !

Comment: @BrianRoach Why would you downvote it ? The question is `how to register a user using smack api` that's it.

Comment: Because that's not a valid question per the FAQ and guidelines? (Yes, that's a rhetorical question).

Comment: @BrianRoach How would you put up a question on the same subject ? Its a clear question _How do I register a user using smack api_. I could do nothing except that empty code.

Comment: Where is the database code? Just calling the set method using the map will not put things in db.

Comment: @JunedAhsan can you help me with the code though an answer

Comment: @SuhailGupta I can help you if you share the complete code, only showing that hashmap setter code will not help me.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Sorry to say but that is all I know. I have written nothing else. While searching I came across the `Registration` class and could do only this.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below.  The code assumes that the XMPP server is running locally (localhost). The `createAccount` method is creating internally a `Registration` packet and sends it through the `connection`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
    XMPPConnection connection=null;
    try
    {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();
        AccountManager accountManager = connection.getAccountManager();
        if(accountManager.supportsAccountCreation())
        {
            accountManager.createAccount("user1", "user1pw");
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        ...
    }
    connection.disconnect();
}
```